# How do I switch base URL between development and production sites?

Tags: uri

The production site is on http://example.com/, while the development site is on http://localhost/~aviram/example.com/. Bringing the production database to the development site breaks all links.

How can I fix this so I can work comfortably and move things between the development and production sites (both running Drupal 8)?

Comment: Use relative paths instead of absolute ones?

Comment: in drupal settings.php you can define your site's base url : $base_url = 'http://example.org';

Comment: @MassoudiMalek, in D8 there is no $base_url in settings.php.

Comment: @avibrazil, you can move D8 around without any problem, all you have to do is clear the cache, so that all content is re-rendered. If you have a problem with links in custom code, you have to show us the code.